# How to import Dynamic web project created in netbeans to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, netbeans-8

I have gone through many sites and videos on youtube and they have shown the importation of normal java project. But what to do for dynamic web project. plz anyone help me fast

Comment: Don't import project, import code.

Comment: I got it done. We need to just import the war file of the net beans project.